# Inheritance in ResourceDictionary (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In WPF, would it be possible for a `ResourceDictionary` (Child.xaml) to inherit from another `ResourceDictionary` (Base.xaml) using only XAML notation.

I tried using the tag `ResourceDictionary` and then try to see if some kind of merge or basedOn was available, but I couldn't find anything.

For example, I have the following (assume) child ResourceDictionary (Child.xaml file):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Is it possible from there derive from another base ResourceDictionary using basedOn or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit from another base ResourceDictionary"? Use in "derived ResourceDictionary" resources from "base ResourceDictionary"?
To do this, a new dictionary is added to "ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries" and theUri "base ResourceDictionary" XAML  is set in its Source.

Comment: You cannot inherit a whole resource dictionary from another so no. But you can merge another resource dictionary in.  You're probably best advised to explain what end result you wish you achieve and ask how to do so.

Comment: As the others already mentioned, you can only merge dictionaries, but there's no inheritance: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries. As you already noted yourself, Styles within resource dictionaries do support inheritance.

Comment: @ewerspej ok, thanks for confirming. At first sight I guessed that maybe there was a way to do it but i see it is not possible.

Comment: @Kiraski *"but i see it is not possible"* - appears like you don't understand. The term "inherit" or "inheritance" is not correct in this context. If your goal is that dictionary B should contain/include all resources defined in dictionary A, then you have to merge dictionary A into B by creating a merged dictionary. This means what you want *is* very much possible. People already provided you with corresponding links to learn how to achieve this.

Comment: @Kiraki you're just getting confused by the terminology. Merging is what you want. It's just called something different for ResourceDictionary's even though it's `BasedOn` for Style's, because, you know, why would MS ever be consistent with something?

Comment: @PeterMoore thanks for the clarification, yes, it's a question of terminology.

Comment: @Kiraski: *How* do you want to use `Base.xaml` in `Child.xaml`? Do you want to base some style in `Child.xaml` on another style in `Base.xaml` or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 I know that the correct way when using dictionary is through merging them but out of curiosity I wanted to know if xaml syntax supported directly some kind of "derived" or "inheritance" mechanisms like we do in OOP with clases.

Comment: A `ResourceDictionary` is nothing but a class so you can derive it from another `ResourceDictionary` - in the code-behind.